# Combine Solr Q and FQ search

Tags: solr

I need to select all documents in a city of a state, which is the better way to make query faster?

```
1. q=*:*, fq=state:IL AND city:chicago

2. q=state:IL,  fq=city:chicago

3. q=state:IL AND city:chicago  (not using fq)
```

If I need to select all documents belong to a person, what would be the best combination? The beginner like me would do this:

```
 q=state:IL AND city:chicago AND name:smith
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual filter queries (proposal 2) are faster as they are cached independently and you may reuse them in a different combination together.

But there are other factors such as cache size, eviction, frequency of content updates (that invalidate the caches), and so on.